# how to disable a key after keypress C# winforms

Tags: c#

I am tring to create a windows form app where I kept some usercontrols to display in a panel.
here I used an usercontrol1 on Main form load. and other usercontrol2 will be opened if F1 key is pressed. and if I want to exit from this usercontrol2 I have to press escape key. so the usercontrol1 will be load to main form again.

now my problem is on pressing F1 again and again usercontrol2 gets refreshed or we can say opens again and again. and the same thing happens when Escape key is pressed.

also I want to use Escape key for exit application.

please provide me a solution which will disable F1 after usercontrol2 is opened. same with Escape key.

```
 private void Weg_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControldisplay();
            
        }

        private void UserControldisplay()
        {
            panelmain1.Controls.Clear();
            UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
            UC.AutoScroll = false;
            UC.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panelmain1.Controls.Add(UC);
            UC.Show();
            this.Focus();
        }
```

```
 private void Weg_Main_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
            {
                openCompanyCreationToolStripMenuItem_Click (null, null);
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
             if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            { 
                openMainToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null);
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            
        }
```

I tried to close applications wiht this.

```
 private void Weg_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.UserClosing)
                return;

            DialogResult result;
            result = MyMessageBox.ShowMessage("Are you sure, you want to exit.", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```